# IPv6 parsing in rust

Tags: rust, ip-address

Here is code to parse an IPv6 address.
An IPv6 address is 128 bits long.
When represented in its printable form, its hextets (1 hextet ==  16 bits) are represented as hexadecimal numbers, and are separated by columns.
For example

```
fe80:0000:0000:0000:8657:e6fe:08d5:5325
```

Note that for each hextet, the left-most `0`s can be ignored. Here is the same address:

```
fe80:0:0:0:8657:e6fe:8d5:5325
```

Finally, if there are several consecutive hextets which value is `0`, they can be omitted and replaced by `::`. Here is the same address again:

```
fe80::8657:e6fe:8d5:5325
```

The `::` can be anywhere, not only in the middle. For instance, these are valid IPv6 addresses:

```
::1
ffff::
```

The null address can be represented as `::`.

Finally, there's a special type of IPv6 addresses that provide compatiblity with IPv4. The last 32 bits of these addresses represent an IPv4, and are represented like this:

```
1111:2222:3333:4444:5555:6666:1.2.3.4
```

The IPv4 MUST be at the end of the address for the IP to be valid.

My code is inspired by the [`go` standard library `ParseIPv6` function](https://golang.org/src/net/ip.go).

The code is a bit long so I posted it [as a gist](https://gist.github.com/little-dude/ad56d56afcd30ea39fafd807e16f05d1) as well (which contains a few tests)

I'd like to know if:

- there are ways to make this code more efficient (even using third party crates)
- is using bytes instead of characters ok? In an IPv6, all the characters are supposed to have an ASCII representation, so I *think* it's ok but I'm not 100% sure. If I have to use characters, it's much more complicated because there's not way to index a string in Rust.

After this long introduction, the code:

```
use std::str::FromStr;

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Eq, PartialEq, Hash, Clone)]
pub struct Ipv6Address(u128);

impl FromStr for Ipv6Address {
    type Err = MalformedAddress;

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        // We'll manipulate bytes instead of UTF-8 characters, because the characters that
        // represent an IPv6 address are supposed to be ASCII characters.
        let bytes = s.as_bytes();

        // The maximimum length of a string representing an IPv6 is the length of:
        //
        //      1111:2222:3333:4444:5555:6666:7777:8888
        //
        // The minimum length of a string representing an IPv6 is the length of:
        //
        //      ::
        //
        if bytes.len() > 38 || bytes.len() < 2 {
            return Err(MalformedAddress(s.into()));
        }

        let mut offset = 0;
        let mut ellipsis: Option<usize> = None;

        // Handle the special case where the IP start with "::"
        if bytes[0] == b':' {
            if bytes[1] == b':' {
                if bytes.len() == 2 {
                    return Ok(Ipv6Address(0));
                }
                ellipsis = Some(0);
                offset += 2;
            } else {
                // An IPv6 cannot start with a single column. It must be a double column.
                // So this is an invalid address
                return Err(MalformedAddress(s.into()));
            }
        }

        // When dealing with IPv6, it's easier to reason in terms of "hextets" instead of octets.
        // An IPv6 is 8 hextets. At the end, we'll convert that array into an u128.
        let mut address: [u16; 8] = [0; 8];

        // Keep track of the number of hextets we process
        let mut hextet_index = 0;

        loop {
            if offset == bytes.len() {
                break;
            }

            // Try to read an hextet
            let (bytes_read, hextet) = read_hextet(&bytes[offset..]);

            // Handle the case where we could not read an hextet
            if bytes_read == 0 {
                match bytes[offset] {
                    // We could not read an hextet because the first character in the slace was ":"
                    // This may be because we have two consecutive columns.
                    b':' => {
                        // Check if already saw an ellipsis. If so, fail parsing, because an IPv6
                        // can only have one ellipsis.
                        if ellipsis.is_some() {
                            return Err(MalformedAddress(s.into()));
                        }
                        // Otherwise, remember the position of the ellipsis. We'll need that later
                        // to count the number of zeros the ellipsis represents.
                        ellipsis = Some(hextet_index);
                        offset += 1;
                        // Continue and try to read the next hextet
                        continue;
                    }
                    // We now the first character does not represent an hexadecimal digit
                    // (otherwise read_hextet() would have read at least one character), and that
                    // it's not ":", so the string does not represent an IPv6 address
                    _ => return Err(MalformedAddress(s.into())),
                }
            }

            // At this point, we know we read an hextet.

            address[hextet_index] = hextet;
            offset += bytes_read;
            hextet_index += 1;

            // If this was the last hextet of if we reached the end of the buffer, we should be
            // done
            if hextet_index == 8 || offset == bytes.len() {
                break
            }

            // Read the next charachter. After a hextet, we usually expect a column, but there's a special
            // case for IPv6 that ends with an IPv4.
            match bytes[offset] {
                // We saw the column, we can continue
                b':' => offset += 1,
                // Handle the special IPv4 case, ie address like. Note that the hextet we just read
                // is part of that IPv4 address:
                //
                // aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd:eeee:ffff:a.b.c.d.
                //                               ^^
                //                               ||
                // hextet we just read, that  ---+|
                // is actually the first byte of  +--- dot we're handling
                // the ipv4.
                b'.' => {
                    // The hextet was actually part of the IPv4, so not that we start reading the
                    // IPv4 at `offset - bytes_read`.
                    let ipv4: u32 = Ipv4Address::parse(&bytes[offset-bytes_read..])?.into();
                    // Replace the hextet we just read by the 16 most significant bits of the
                    // IPv4 address (a.b in the comment above)
                    address[hextet_index - 1] = ((ipv4 & 0xffff_0000) >> 16) as u16;
                    // Set the last hextet to the 16 least significant bits of the IPv4 address
                    // (c.d in the comment above)
                    address[hextet_index] = (ipv4 & 0x0000_ffff) as u16;
                    hextet_index += 1;
                    // After successfully parsing an IPv4, we should be done.
                    // If there are bytes left in the buffer, or if we didn't read enough hextet,
                    // we'll fail later.
                    break;
                }
                _ => return Err(MalformedAddress(s.into())),
            }
        } // end of loop

        // If we exited the loop, we should have reached the end of the buffer.
        // If there are trailing characters, parsing should fail.
        if offset < bytes.len() {
            return Err(MalformedAddress(s.into()));
        }

        if hextet_index == 8 && ellipsis.is_some() {
            // We parsed an address that looks like 1111:2222::3333:4444:5555:6666:7777,
            // ie with an empty ellipsis.
            return Err(MalformedAddress(s.into()));
        }

        // We didn't parse enough hextets, but this may be due to an ellipsis
        if hextet_index < 8 {
            if let Some(ellipsis_index) = ellipsis {
                // Count how many zeros the ellipsis accounts for
                let nb_zeros = 8 - hextet_index;
                // Shift the hextet that we read after the ellipsis by the number of zeros
                for index in (ellipsis_index..hextet_index).rev() {
                    address[index+nb_zeros] = address[index];
                    address[index] = 0;
                }
            } else {
                return Err(MalformedAddress(s.into()));
            }
        }

        // Build the IPv6 address from the array of hextets
        return Ok(Ipv6Address(
                ((address[0] as u128) << 112)
                + ((address[1] as u128) << 96)
                + ((address[2] as u128) << 90)
                + ((address[3] as u128) << 64)
                + ((address[4] as u128) << 48)
                + ((address[5] as u128) << 32)
                + ((address[6] as u128) << 16)
                + address[7] as u128))
    }
}
```

Here are the helpers I'm using:

```
/// Check whether an ASCII character represents an hexadecimal digit
fn is_hex_digit(byte: u8) -> bool {
    match byte {
        b'0' ... b'9' | b'a' ... b'f' | b'A' ... b'F' => true,
        _ => false,
    }
}

/// Convert an ASCII character that represents an hexadecimal digit into this digit
fn hex_to_digit(byte: u8) -> u8 {
    match byte {
        b'0' ... b'9' => byte - b'0',
        b'a' ... b'f' => byte - b'a' + 10,
        b'A' ... b'F' => byte - b'A' + 10,
        _ => unreachable!(),
    }
}

/// Read up to four ASCII characters that represent hexadecimal digits, and return their value, as
/// well as the number of characters that were read. If not character is read, `(0, 0)` is
/// returned.
fn read_hextet(bytes: &[u8]) -> (usize, u16) {
    let mut count = 0;
    let mut digits: [u8; 4] = [0; 4];

    for b in bytes {
        if is_hex_digit(*b) {
            digits[count] = hex_to_digit(*b);
            count += 1;
            if count == 4 {
                break;
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    if count == 0 {
        return (0, 0);
    }

    let mut shift = (count - 1) * 4;
    let mut res = 0;
    for digit in &digits[0..count] {
        res += (*digit as u16) << shift;
        if shift >= 4 {
            shift -= 4;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    (count, res)
}
```

I don't handle IPv4 parsing for now, so I'm just using this:

```
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Eq, PartialEq, Hash, Clone)]
pub struct Ipv4Address(u32);

impl Ipv4Address {
    fn parse(_: &[u8]) -> Result<u32, MalformedAddress> {
        unimplemented!();
    }
}
```

Finally here is the error type I'm using:

```
use std::fmt;
use std::error::Error;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct MalformedAddress(String);

impl fmt::Display for MalformedAddress {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "malformed address: \"{}\"", self.0)
    }
}

impl Error for MalformedAddress {
    fn description(&self) -> &str {
        "the string cannot be parsed as an IP address"
    }

    fn cause(&self) -> Option<&Error> {
        None
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

*This is not a full review, I just looked at this very quickly and noticed a part which looked more like c than rust*

The functions `is_hex_digit` and `hex_to_digit` do almost the same thing and could be combined to

```
fn hex_digit(byte: u8) -> Option<u8> {
    match byte {
        b'0' ... b'9' => Some(byte - b'0'),
        b'a' ... b'f' => Some(byte - b'a' + 10),
        b'A' ... b'F' => Some(byte - b'A' + 10),
        _ => None,
    }
}
```

Then this part

```
   if is_hex_digit(*b) {
        digits[count] = hex_to_digit(*b);
        count += 1;
        if count == 4 {
            break;
        }
    } else {
        break;
    }
```

could be written as:

```
   if let Some(digit) = hex_digit(*b) {
        digits[count] = digit;
        count += 1;
        if count == 4 {
            break;
        }
   } else {
        break;
   }
```

The second thing which cross my mind is the absence of unit tests, this is a perfect case where it makes sense to add unit-tests for the parsing of the general case and all corner cases.

In the last statement of a block explicit return is not needed.

```
  // Build the IPv6 address from the array of hextets
    return Ok(Ipv6Address(
            ((address[0] as u128) << 112)
            + ((address[1] as u128) << 96)
            + ((address[2] as u128) << 90)
            + ((address[3] as u128) << 64)
            + ((address[4] as u128) << 48)
            + ((address[5] as u128) << 32)
            + ((address[6] as u128) << 16)
            + address[7] as u128))
```

should be replaced with a shorter single `Ok(ipv6)`

The address conversions could be done with the `let ipv6=unsafe{ std::mem::transmute::<[u16;8],u128>(address)` but that could probably introduce some issues with the endianness of the target system and it *is* unsafe for a reason. Some variation in `into_bytes` and `from_bytes` is also possible here. But I would at least replace the addition with bitwise `or` which looks cleaner.

```
      // Build the IPv6 address from the array of hextets
       let ipv6:u128 = ((address[0] as u128) << 112)
        | ((address[1] as u128) << 96)
        | ((address[2] as u128) << 90)
        | ((address[3] as u128) << 64)
        | ((address[4] as u128) << 48)
        | ((address[5] as u128) << 32)
        | ((address[6] as u128) << 16)
        | (( address[7] as u128));
        Ok(ipv6)
```